# dictionary get method for list of dataclass objects - find dataclass with specific variable value in list of dataclasses

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses

###It seems to me there has to be nicer way find a dataclass object than to loop through all to find the specific one.

```
#My way, that I hope to improve:
def changeValueOf(primaryKey):
    for item in self.addlist:
        if item.id == primaryKey:
            # Do stuff...


#Basics:
listOfKeys = "AA BB CC".split()

@dataclass
class Feld:
    id: str
    value1: str
    value2: str
    value3: str

self.addlist: List = []

for element in Daten:
    data = Feld(element[0], element[1], element[2], int(element[3]))
    self.addlist.append(data)
```

Comment: Why is `addlist` a list and not a dict from `id` to the object?

Comment: Also it does not make much sense for `addlist` to be part of the class.

Comment: @DeepSpace there might be a reason why an operation of a class instance mutates the class instance ‍♂️

Comment: This question needs more focus. Consider editing it

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon Indeed, but that is not what OP is attempting to do.

Comment: @DeepSpace I don’t even know what the OP is trying to do. The question is a bit vague.

Comment: linkToCorrectDataClass = self.addlist[0].get_instance_by_id('BB')
That is what I wanted to have, instead of using a for loop. 
Selecting one specific dataclass in a list of dataclasses.

Comment: The code above, at least #Basics:  was not real code but mostly unsorted snippets to explain what I was doing. I will write a mini program next time to be more consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common and efficient approach to keeping track of all instances of a class is to store each instance in a class variable of a dict by a certain key, and use a class method to retrieve an instance by the key. In your case, use the `id` attribute as the key:

```
from typing import ClassVar
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Feld:
    _id_to_instance: ClassVar[dict] = {}
    id: str
    value: str

    def __post_init__(self):
        self._id_to_instance[self.id] = self

    @classmethod
    def get_instance_by_id(cls, id):
        return cls._id_to_instance[id]
```

so that:

```
for id, value in ('id1', 'value1'), ('id2', 'value2'):
    Feld(id, value)

print(Feld.get_instance_by_id('id2'))
```

outputs:

```
Feld(id='id2', value='value2')
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/KgQH5y

Comment: Sounds promising but does not solve my request.
I finally access a list of Feld classes. The list does not have the method get_instance_by_id() and I cannot ask a single class about the existence of other classes in the list - or am I wrong?!

Comment: I am wrong .... I just access self.addlist[0].get_instance_by_id('Datum') and I will get the element of the list that I need. Perfect!
Thanks for the help. I am just into Python for a very few weeks.